# How can I get a released version for every project on Jira?

Tags: php, rest, symfony, jira-rest-api

I'm working with Symfony 2.8 (PHP) and I'd like to get all versions for every project on Jira via API Rest Jira, and then to filter theme in order to select only the released versions.

I've found this methods but I dont know how to use the 'expand' parameter for reaching versions

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CeSy.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcp47.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st step:  at config.yml

For more information about Guzzle configuration: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

```
csa_guzzle:
    clients:
        jira:
            config: 
                base_uri: "https://jira.*****.*****.***/rest/api/2/"
                timeout: 20.0
                headers:
                    Accept: "application/json"
                    Content-Type: "application/json"
                verify: false
                auth: ['api','password','Basic']
```

2nd step: create a GuzzleHttp client service for sending a request to the api

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service\Atlassian\Jira\Client;

use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClientHttp;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;


class GuzzleClient
{
    /**
     * Guzzle Client.
     *
     * @var GuzzleClientHttp
     */
    protected $guzzle;

    /**
     * Response object of request.
     *
     * @var ResponseInterface
     */
    protected $response;

    /**
     * GuzzleClient constructor.
     *
     * @param GuzzleClientHttp $guzzle
     */
    public function __construct(GuzzleClientHttp $guzzle)
    {
        $this->guzzle = $guzzle ?: new GuzzleClientHttp();
    }


    public function send($method = 'GET', $url, $parameters = [])
    {
        try {
            $this->response = $this->guzzle->request($method, $url, ['query' => $parameters]);
        } catch (ServerException $exception) {
            $this->response = $exception->getResponse();
        }

        return $this->getContents();
    }

    /**
     * Return the contents as a string of last request.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContents()
    {
        return $this->response->getBody()->getContents();
    }


    /**
     * Getter for GuzzleClient.
     *
     * @return GuzzleClientHttp
     */
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->guzzle;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for last Response.
     *
     * @return ResponseInterface
     */
    public function getResponse()
    {
        return $this->response;
}
```

3th step: crate a service for getting all versions

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service\Atlassian\Jira;

use AppBundle\Service\Atlassian\Jira\Client\GuzzleClient;

class ApiService
{

    /**
     * Client HTTP.
     *
     * @var GuzzleClient
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * ApiService constructor.
     *
     * @param GuzzleClient $client
     */
    public function __construct(GuzzleClient $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
     * Get all released versions for a given projectKey.
     *
     * @param string $projectKey
     * @return null|array
     */
    public function getVersions($projectKey)
    {
        $versions = json_decode($this->client->send('GET', 'project/'.$projectKey."/versions/"));
        for($i=0;$i< count($versions); $i++)
        {
            if($versions[$i]->released== false)
            {
                $result = $versions[$i]->name;
            }
        }

        return $versions;
    }

}
```